# ¿Por que al agregarle el efecto de opacidad Se me oculta detras de otros elementos?

Tags: css, bootstrap, css3, animación

Ejemplo exacto de lo que pasa [aqui](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QQoyeg?editors=1100)

Me explico, si ven el ejemplo pueden notar que son solo dos animaciones sencillas, dos imagenes que llegan suben dando vueltas, y un texto que se empieza a mostrar mediante opacidad.

En esta parte final esta mi problema, si no agrego el efecto el div queda sobre las dos animaciones que me pasa, pero si agrego el efecto auqnue funciona queda detras de las formas que entran dando vueltas.

¿Alguien sabe por que pasa esto?

De paso muchas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso sucede porque estan en capas distintas los elementos, siendo los animados, estan en capas superiores y la del `contentdata` no.

Te sugiero revisar acerca de z-index y el posicionamiento por capas en css3, pero por lo pronto te sugiero probar agregando esto:

```
.contentdata{
  /*...otros estilos...*/    
  position: absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

De hecho el `z-index` que recomiendo es cualquiera superior a 3.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer uso de la propiedad en css `"z-index:;"`. Lo que consigues con ello es "ordenar en capas" según te interesan los contenidos, o que viene a ser la "PROFUNDIDAD WEB".

Durante el flujo normal de trabajo, es común que al ejecutarse el HTML, este se pone "por capas" a demás de uno encima de otro al tocar estilos CSS, float, position "relative, absolute o fixed", margenes, etc, podemos llegar a encontrar problemas como el que presentas.

Haciendo uso del estilo css `Z-index:;` solo debes aplicar un número del 1 a 9999, que digamos son capas de atrás hacia delante, o superposición de etiquetas HTML.

Cuanto mayor es el número antes estará visible o "mas arriba". 
Un ejemplo claro de su utilidad, es utilizar para el botón flotante como "scroll to top, redes sociales o barra de navegación", partes imprescindibles en cuanto accesibilidad o usbilidad web, con `z-index: 9999;` de tal forma que al tener el máximo valor, SIEMPRE estará visible, accesible, clicable por encima del resto de contenidos de cara al usuario.

Ten en cuenta que tienes mas de 9999 capas ya que se pueden aplicar números negativos, aunque en realidad nunca he visto utilizar menos de "z-index:-1;" cuando se quiere forzar algo a que desaparezca por detrás en ciertos casos especiales.

Un caso especial de aplicación, sería en relación al posicionamiento web SEO. Los motores de búsqueda, pierden información de l web con contenidos ocultos "display". Según la documentación sobre SEO, los motores de búsqueda no les gusta los contenidos ocultos puesto que les cuesta mas acceder a ellos o directamente no acceden. Con `z-index:-1;`, si estará disponible al buscador pero no visible al usuario, quedando activo pero "oculto"

En tu caso, basta con poner el que quieres encima con un `z-index` superior al otro.

Saludos.